# Regarding infinite sets, is this enough to prove that $2$ sets are $1-1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The info given is : Let $A$ and $B$ be infinite sets, there exists an onto map $f:B\to A$ Is this enough to say that $f$ is $1-1$ or what small proof would that look like?

I ultimately need to show that their cardinality is equal, which I believe I need to show both onto and $1-1$ is true, is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried constructing such surjective maps for yourself? You will see that the answer is no.

Comment: I ultimately need to show that their cardinality is equal, which I believe I need to show both onto and 1-1 is true, is there a way around this?

Comment: $f~:~B\to A$ being onto is not enough proof to show that there exists a bijection between $B$ and $A$.  For example $f~:~\Bbb R\to \Bbb Z$ given by $x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$ is an onto function but $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$ have different cardinalities and no bijection exists between them.

Comment: Interesting, is there any other way to prove that the cardinality is equal between A and B using thr given info?

Comment: If you want to prove that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality you can explicitly find a bijection between $A$ and $B$, or you may find an onto function from $A$ to $B$ *as well as* simultaneously finding another onto function this time from $B$ to $A$.  Alternatively still, you could find a one-to-one function from $A$ to $B$ as well as simultaneously finding a one-to-one function from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: "is there any other way to prove that the cardinality is equal between A and B using thr given info?"  No!  Because it is *NOT* true.  And JMoravitz counter example shows.

Comment: Is there a way to show that there is some subset C of B which has the same cardinality of A?

Comment: So long as you accept the axiom of choice, yes, but that is likely getting outside the scope of what we should be talking about here.  For each $a\in A$ simply pick a single element of $\{b~:~f(b)=a\}$ to use in our subset $C$.

Comment: How does an subset with a single element have the same cardinality of an infinite set?

Comment: It is questions like that which is why I say this is outside the scope of what you should probably be worrying about.  I never said that a subset with a single element has the same cardinality as an infinite set.  I said that the set of arbitrarily chosen representatives has the same cardinality as the codomain.  For example, consider a finite example: $\{A,a,B,b\}\to \{1,2\}$ where $f(A)=f(a)=1$ and $f(B)=f(b)=2$.  We choose one of the however many preimages of $1$... for example $A$., to be included in our set, and we choose one of the however many preimages of $2$., for example $b$...

Comment: ... and indeed, we see that $\{A,b\}$ has the same cardinality as $\{1,2\}$.  The idea is the same for the infinite case., keeping in mind that we have infinitely many choices to make with potentially infinitely many options available for each choice.  Hence, the reason we need the axiom of choice.  Such a selection would not be possible without the axiom of choice.

Comment: I'll try to explain again via means of a metaphor.  Suppose you have a set of students (*set $B$*) and a set of classrooms (*set $A$*).  Each student is in a single classroom at a time (*we have a function from $B$ to $A$*) and each classroom has at least one student in it (*the function is onto*).  We can if we want choose a class leader from each class (*choose a representative*) and the set of those class leaders is a subset of the set of students has the same cardinality as the set of classrooms.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, That makes a lot of sense. I will get back to studying cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a surjective map from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$:
$$n\mapsto\lfloor n\rfloor$$
In this case, there are infinitely many real numbers mapping to a fixed $n$. However, there is no *bijective* such map, because the cardinality of $\mathbb Z$ is strictly less than that of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I ultimately need to show that their cardinality is equal, which I believe I need to show both onto and 1-1 is true, is there a way around this?

Comment: @PabloTores The statement is already outright false.

Comment: How would I go about proving this then? I'm stuck.

Comment: @PabloTores You can't; it's false! I have given a counterexample.

Comment: No, I mean proving that 2 infinite sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: How is this a counter example?  JMoravitz provides a counterexample in the comments.

Comment: @fleablood done.